# What does '*' signify in python function declarations ?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ** and * do for python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters)

I saw this in a function definition, this was located in heapq.py, the python implementation of a heap queue

```
def merge(*iterables):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this part](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) of the Python tutorial and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters).